# Spring boot 3.2.0-RC1 - java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application that is build on Spring Boot version 3.2.0-M3 and it works perfectly with Java 17. However, when I am upgrade Spring Boot version 3.2.0-RC1, I can successfully build the project, but I encounter an exception when trying to start the application. I am looking for assistance with this issue.

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 1140260872 but got 0 bytes)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:399) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:198) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.read(JarInputStream.java:194) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.closeEntry(ZipInputStream.java:142) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.getNextEntry(ZipInputStream.java:120) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:84) ~[?:?]
        at java.util.jar.JarInputStream.<init>(JarInputStream.java:61) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.NonClosingJarInputStream.<init>(NonClosingJarInputStream.java:37) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.UrlJar.createJarInputStream(UrlJar.java:47) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.AbstractInputStreamJar.reset(AbstractInputStreamJar.java:160) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.AbstractInputStreamJar.getManifest(AbstractInputStreamJar.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processManifest(StandardJarScanner.java:444) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:332) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:275) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:238) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) [tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) [tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) [tomcat-embed-jasper-10.1.10.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4850) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:845) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) [?:?]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145) [?:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:866) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:433) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:488) [tomcat-embed-core-10.1.15.jar!/:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:501) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at com.test. MyAppRestBootApp$1.getTomcatWebServer(MyAppRestBootApp.java:110) [!/:?]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:218) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:188) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:610) [spring-context-6.1.0-RC1.jar!/:6.1.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:748) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:450) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) [spring-boot-3.2.0-RC1.jar!/:3.2.0-RC1]
        at com.test. MyAppRestBootApp.main(MyAppRestBootApp.java:97) [!/:?]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you building against pre-release versions? In any case, either the JAR is somehow corrupt, or there is a problem in your Java version. Consider deleting the file from your local Maven repository and forcing a re-download, and try upgrading to the latest version of Java 17 (or downgrading to an earlier version if you're using the latest).

Comment: I was able to build and run with Spring boot 3.1.1 as well. And tried by deleting all the spring jar from local maven repo, but no luck with 3.2.0-RC1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying out the release candidate. This is a [known issue with RC1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38047). You can work around it by configuring your app to use the classic loader implementation. With Maven, that would look like this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <loaderImplementation>CLASSIC</loaderImplementation>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

And with Gradle:

```
bootJar {
  loaderImplementation = org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.LoaderImplementation.CLASSIC
}
```